# how to access website hosted on google cloud only from one static ip address

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have hosted my website on Google cloud,i want to open my website only from own static ip address of my network premises.

Is there any workaround using .htaccess to implement this method.

Kindly advice us.

with thanks and regards,

Vijay maurya

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is possible using htaccess but another solution is to [setup a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#addingafirewall) on Compute Engine that will only allow access from your IP :

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create FIREWALL_RULE \
         --allow PROTOCOL[:PORT[-PORT]] [PROTOCOL:[PORT[-PORT]]]... \
         [--source-ranges CIDR_RANGE [CIDR_RANGE]]
```

where `CIDR_RANGE` is replace with `YOUR_IP/32`